# Is it right to move all responsibility for cloning objects to user of a library?

Tags: ruby, pass-by-reference, cloning

I'm not that knowledgeable in this matter so I decided to ask here. Let's say we have some 'library' in Ruby (or any other pass by reference scripting language):

```
class Moo
    attr_accessor :bar
    def initialize
        self
    end
end

a = 'a string'
b = Moo.new
b.bar = a
```

`b.bar` will obviously be the same object as `a`.

Is it right to leave it as it is in *all cases* so programmer who need them separate will do cloning manually? That's the only sane idea I ended up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [the principle of least surprise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), it is correct to maintain the reference to the assigned object as you've done.

If you *did* internally `dup` the object assigned to `bar`, it would be *extremely* frustrating to a consumer of your library who *wanted* `bar` to refer to the identical object.

```
> class Moo
>  attr_accessor :bar
> end
=> nil
> a = 'a string'
=> "a string"
> b = Moo.new
=> #<Moo:0x2bfd238>
> b.bar = a
=> "a string"
> a.upcase!
=> "A STRING"
> b.bar # should be uppercase as expected since `a` was modified *in-place*
=> "A STRING"
> b.bar = a.dup # now modifications to `a` will not affect `bar`
=> "A STRING"
> a.downcase!
=> "a string"
> b.bar
=> "A STRING"
```

<sub>As a side note, `def initialize() self end` is completely unnecessary as it is identical to the default `initialize`.</sub>

Comment: I tried to find the answer to this for quite some time. Thank you.

As for default `initialize` it is indeed works. I remember it didn't some time ago, but it seems there was another problem unrelated to existence of `initialize`.